# What is the part number of this FET with top marking "NSC1"

Tags: identification, semiconductors

[image: Photo of PCB K-2.png]

LCD switch circuit part in laptop.

The marking is marked "NSC1".

"a" is the gate and 5 volts is applied
"b" is the drain
"c" is the source

3.3 volts is applied to b, and if a gate has 5 volts, 3.3 volts are crossed by c.

The fact that the gate voltage is higher than the drain is an N-channel FET.

Then "a" is the gate, "b" is the drain, and "c" is the source N-channel FET.

However, for most SOT-23 type FETs, "c" is the drain.

I need the product name of the FET where "c" is the source (as in the picture).

Maybe it is a P-channel FET. But if it is a p-channel fet, The gate voltage must be lower than the source voltage. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you confirm by diode test function on a multimeter that your suggested D/S are actually correct on both the examples? There should be a body diode anode on S and cathode on D. Some circuit configurations use MOSFETs in reverse.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPkjAOr-8l8&t=363s

Comment: The fact is this is part of the YouTube video that I did not understand and captured. 
The 3:40 part confirms the problem that the 3.3 volt on signal is not caught in the LED liquid crystal panel.
And he traces the problem.
And the 5:50 part is the question I'm putting up right now.
As I explained and in the video too, a is 5 volts and b is 3.5 volts.
c is 0.2 volts.
And from 7:10, the problem is solved after replacing the device with another device.
a is 5 volts, b is 3.3 volts, c is 3.3 volts.
The liquid crystal also works normally.

Comment: Sorry. It seems to be a P channel fet.  But if it is a p-channel fet, The gate voltage must be lower than the source voltage. Isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Gate voltage higher than source will just keep the MOSFET 'off' for an enhancement-mode P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: yes, but I think that's on.